# Algorithms for Optimization of Integer Subset Linking

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

Consider having two sets of integer values that are divided in multiple subsets. The two sets exist of the same set of values but the order and the division into subsets differ. The idea is to link the subsets from the first set with these from the second set in such way that every individual value in each subset of the first set is linked to a same individual value of a subset of the second set. No value can be linked with two others. In one linking step multiple values can be linked between only one subset of the first set with only one subset of the second set. The goal is to reduce the amount of linking steps as much as possible.

The question is: are there algorithms around for doing this kind of linking as optimal as possible?

I have done some research in several fields of mathematical optimization, such as Linear Programming, Integer Programming, Combinatorial optimization and Operations Research but none of the algorithms seem to cover this problem. Do you guys have any ideas, fields or algorithms to optimize these kinds of problems and make me head in the right direction?

**For example:**

Two sets of integers with two subsets:

[[1, 2, 2] [2, 3, 3]]

and

[[1, 2, 3] [2, 2, 3]].

Now the first linking set could be to link the first subset of the first set 1[1] with the first subset of the second set 2[1].

This is one step and leads to a link between: 1 - 1 - 1 and 2 - 1 - 1 and a link between 1 - 1 - 2 and 2 - 1 - 2. Now the sets will look like this:

[[**1, 2**, 2] [2, 3, 3]]

and

[[**1, 2**, 3] [2, 2, 3]].

The next step could be linking 1[1] with 2[2], leading to a link between 1 - 1 - 3 and 2 - 2 - 1 and the sets will look like this:

[[**1, 2, 2**] [2, 3, 3]]

and

[[**1, 2**, 3] [**2**, 2, 3]].

The third step could be linking 1[2] with 2[1]. Resulting in:

[[**1, 2, 2**] [2, **3**, 3]]

and

[[**1, 2, 3**] [**2**, 2, 3]].

And the fourth step could then be linking 1[2] to 2[2]. Resulting in:

[[**1, 2, 2**] [**2, 3, 3**]]

and

[[**1, 2, 3**] [**2, 2, 3**]], which means every value is linked. This solution costs four steps.

When having larger sets, all subsets can be linked to all other subsets of the other set, but that will result in many steps. Is there a algorithm around that optimizes the number of steps?

Comment: I think we could use an example here!

Comment: Hope the example helps you understanding the problem!

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with mathematical optimization. I believe you just want a data structure to make searching easier/faster.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: I think you did not read the problem outline very well. The goal I want to reach is to optimize the number of linking steps, which is absolutely a mathematical optimization. I do not care about data structures and I don't care about speed that much, as long as the algorithm is fast enough to solve the problem within reasonable time. I hope you want to reread the problem and you can point out certain directions/algorithms.

Comment: In Step#2: Why not connect 1-1-2 with 2-2-1 & 1-1-3 with 2-2-2?

Comment: @BassemAkl: Thanks for your answer! (I did not understand you in the right way in the first place, but now I do.) Yes, that would have been a possbility too, when 1-1-2 would not have been linked to 2-1-2 in the first step. But you are right, there are many possibilities and my example shows only one. But that exactly makes it a optimization problem.

Comment: Hopefully my edit will add more clearance to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

*Even this is not an answer, but I think this is a step in defining the problem toward finding a solution.*

**Note:** The following example of input/output was an edit. I disagree with the rejecting votes, and **I URGE everyone to read carefully before voting to approve or reject any edit.**

*This would open a discussion about the votes that are non-carefully casted. Still is a constructive discussion but here is not its place.*

> Consider the following example: It is less costly (less using of sub-sets) to use the 3nd sub-set of the first list than using the 2nd and 5th sub-sets.  [image: example of optimizing a linking]

**The algorithm**:

1. Define the smaller list: List #2
2. Create a counting list of all items in all sub-lists of list #2.
3. You will have this counting list {[item:count]}: {[1:3], [2:2], [3:1], [4:2], [5:1]}.
4. Now, your problem instead of linking (i.e. index-dependent) the sub-sets. It is to find the min number of sub-sets of list #1. That their items would give the count of the counting list.
5. A simple try of each possible combination would definitely get the answer.. but I think from point #4 we can think of a better solution containing some conditions to minimize the combination tries.

Hopefully, this suggestion would help in giving a hint towards finding a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving an idea of a possible first step! (I cannot upvote yet) Defining subsets could indeed be a first step in reducing the number of linking steps, as it will reduce the amount of subsets involved.
Two next steps are when using this first step: Coming up with an algorithm to minimize the amount of linking steps required in a subset and finding a algorithm to find the possible subsets without brute force.
To not restrict any creativity: This is a possible first step, but if anyone has other ideas, they are very welcome too!

Comment: @HdG, you are welcome. I just wonder why my edit was rejected for very strange reasons like "promoting a product"!! and "not related to the original question"!! You see people cast votes without reading the answers/comments/edits!